# Disable centering the grid line for chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js, charts

So I got this problem with d3js which I'm not sure how to address. The point is, when I am drawing the grid lines for my plot, when there is no data, my 0 line on Y scale gets centered by the d3 scale function. I'd like to force it to be at the bottom of the chart:

[image: make the grid line a bottom line]

Here's some code:

```
const getYScale = (data: Data[], size: Size) => {
  let maxY: number | undefined = d3.max(data, d => d.value);
  if (!maxY) {
    maxY = 0;
  }
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([size.height, 0]);
  yScale.domain([0, maxY + 0.1 * maxY]);
  return yScale;
};

const makeYGrid = (
  yScale: d3.ScaleLinear<number, number>,
  chart: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, {}, HTMLElement, any>,
  size: Size
) => {
  const yTicsValues = yScale.ticks(10);
  const yGrid = chart.append('g').attr('class', 'y-grid');

  yGrid
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${size.wOffset},0)`)
    .attr('class', 'y-grid-lines')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(yTicsValues)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', d => yScale(d))
    .attr('x2', size.wSpace)
    .attr('y2', d => yScale(d))
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);
};
```

When `attr('y1', d => yScale(d))` gets a d of value 0, the returned value is half of the height (`size.height`) instead of full height.

Comment: I think the problem might derive from `if (!maxY) { maxY = 0; }` What happens if you write `maxY = 1`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the case. If I set 1, than I get 10 lines from 0 to 1 with distance od 0.1 - and I just want one line for the zero value and nothing more. It's working bad with or without this fragment of code.

Comment: This may seem naive but to move the x axis down to the bottom you actually need to attach attributes to the x axis and not the y. Need more code to properly debug.

Comment: Hi Mikes. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Hi! No. :) Thank You!